# Header Footer are gone/wrong randomly

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I generate 100 pages use this library, but unfortunately the Header and Footer are gone randomly. These are arguments I pass to library:

```
"--javascript-delay 5000 --enable-javascript --debug-javascript " + 
"-T 47mm -B 27mm -L 13mm -R 13mm --header-spacing 8 --header-html " + 
SomeHeaderURL + 
" --footer-spacing 5 --footer-html " + 
SomeFooterURL
```

For example,

header are gone for first 8 pages, and Footer only shows around last 10 pages, while other pages' Footer are either not showing at all or page number not replaced.

Can anyone advise what happens?

Note:

I use wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt) version

Comment: Try downgrading wkhtmltopdf's binary version. It solves problems a lot of times actually.

Comment: But I found this issue has been occuring since around 5 years ago, so I don't think older version is better.